Norm inequality about positive definite matrix, along with its symmetric form and skew symmetric form
I have difficulty in solving the following problem (P4.2.3 in 《Matrix Computations》)
Suppose $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ be positive definite, and set T = (A+$A^T$)/2, show that $||A^{-1}||_2\leq ||T^{-1}||_2$ and $x^T A^{-1}x\leq x^TT^{-1}x , \forall x\in \mathbb{R}^n $.

My attepmt:
It is clear that A and T are both positive definite.
And we have $||A^{-1}||_2 = \frac{1}{\lambda_\min(A)}, ||T^{-1}||_2 = \frac{1}{\lambda_\min(T)}$, but I don't know how to prove $\lambda_\min(A) \geq \lambda_\min(T)$.

Any help will be appreciated!

Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match many users' quality standards, so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. This will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Hint: write $A=T^{1/2}(I+K)T^{1/2}$ where $K=T^{-1/2}\left(\frac{A-A^T}{2}\right)T^{-1/2}$.

Thanks for your hint! And I see that using $\lambda(A)$ to represent $||A^{-1}||$ is not strict.
